# How to filter data using ajax in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have added filter functionalty in the listing of users.filer by alphabetical order.
I have send ajax request in the controller but its not send me the filtered data.

Here is my code

```
if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            //$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
            $this->_helper->getHelper('layout')->disableLayout();
            //die('sdfdsf');
            if(isset($params['txt_username']) && !empty($params['txt_username'])) {
                $select->where(PREFIX_USERS . 'username like "%' . $params['txt_username'] . '%"');
                $this->view->test_array = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

                //$this->_helper->P($ajax_parameters);
                //echo $_SESSION['user_list_ajax_search'];
                //$this->view->pageParams = $_SESSION['user_list_ajax_search'];
                //$select->where(PREFIX_USERS . 'username like "%' . $_SESSION['user_list_ajax_search'] . '%"');

            }
        }


        //echo $select->__toString();
        $data = $obj_user->fetchAll($select);

        # Paging section
        $page = $this->_getParam('page', 1);
        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($data);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(2);//PAGING_RESULT_PER_PAGE
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
        $paginator->setPageRange(PAGING_PAGES_RANGE_PER_PAGE);
        $this->view->users = $paginator;
```

Comment: can you post your JS function and relevant html too

Comment: What are you trying to do? you should filter data in Controller/action, and use "quote into" in your SQL query...

Comment: this code piece belongs to controller action...i just want to filter data according to the keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These :

```
$params['txt_username']
```

Should probably be :

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('txt_username')
```

or use :

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Unless its there and you did not post that piece of codes.

Comment: There is no problem in receiving the parameter, the actual problem is that when we receive data from ajax is not adding data in response and does not effecting the paging...